# How to pass JS variable to PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is my first dabbling in Ajax and I'm confused.

**Problem:** JS variable doesn't seem to get passed to php through Ajax.

I get this notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: text in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\ref_files\delete.php on line 31

Line 31 is: `$name = $_POST['text'];`

So the problem seems to be that '`text`' is not being passed to the php as far as I can tell?

Both the JS and the PHP are in delete.php which is included in WhatsNew.php.

I get `Response:`  displayed on the page, as well as an alert saying "success".

There is a value in 'text', I have tested it with alert(text).

**JavaScript + Ajax**

```
<script>

var text = $('#title').text()

 $.ajax({
         url: "WhatsNew.php",
         type: "post",
         cache: "false",
         data: text,
         success: function(){
             alert("success");
         },
         error: function(){
             alert("failure");
         }
     });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['text'];
echo "Response: " . $name;
 ?>
```

*If more information is required it will be posted beyond this point.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change data to:

```
data: {text: something},
```

and also change the name of the variable in js, as the compiler won't know which text to take, like:

```
var something = $('#title').text();
```

Please do comment if this does not work!

Try this in php on a different file with some response in success:

```
<?php 
echo "hello"; 
$name = $_POST['text']; 
echo "<label id='1'>Response: " . $name . "</label>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Ok so I've made the changes but I still get the same error, undefined 'something' now on $name = $_POST['something']. @SML

Comment: the `$_POST['text']` will be the variable stated at the start of your data
`data: {text (this one):something}`.

Comment: Success alert is still there but same error. (with namechange obviously)

Comment: Full code added. I just expected the ajax code to run when the 'delete.php' code was required by the previous file

Comment: I think that you need to trigger it with something like `$(document).ready(function(){ajax call});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84360/discussion-between-sml-and-piman).

Comment: also remember to add in a response to your success to make changes to the page!

Answer (score 0):

you need to change

```
data: text,
```

to

```
data: {text:text},
```

Comment: I still get:

Notice: Undefined index: text in C:\xampp\htdocs\Website\ref_files\delete.php on line 30

Answer (score 0):

You are on track, just one modification:

```
data: {text:text},
```

You need to send `text` as key to posted data.

Comment: I still get the same error using this, any ideas what else I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the document to be ready before trying to read `$('#title').text()`.

Just wrap everything in `$(function() {...})`, (and `data:{text:text}` as others have pointed out).

```
$(function() {
    var text = $('#title').text();
    $.ajax({
        url: "WhatsNew.php",
        type: "post",
        cache: "false",
        data: {text:text},
        success: function(){
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
     });
});
```